How to stop processing task
How to stop an "ex" like that. The cancellation token is not always supported in Execute method. I would always like to kill task.
try
{
    var ex = Execute(parameters, cancellationToken, performContext);

    await Task.WhenAny(ex, ThrowIfCancellationRequested(ex, cancellationToken));

    return;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    _loggerService.LogError(ex,
        "JobBase execute internal with raw params without job semaphore.");
    throw;
}


private async Task ThrowIfCancellationRequested(Task task,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await Task.Delay(5000, cancellationToken);
            cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        }
    }
    catch
    {
        task.Dispose();
    }
}

protected override async Task Execute(Parameter parameter,
    CancellationToken cancellationToken,
    PerformContext performContext = null)
{
    while (true)
    {
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
    }
}

